# DevExtreme and Aurelia integration

Tags: aurelia, devextreme

DevExtreme support angular directives as shown on [this example page for dxDataGrid](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/?search=grid%20angular&version=15_1&approach=Knockout). How can I achieve the same with Aurelia?

Examples showing the integration:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIZj6hOFg0o
2. http://blog.falafel.com/getting-started-with-devexpress-and-angularjs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DevExtreme does not support integration with Aurelia out-of-the-box.

But you can try to create the [Custom Elements](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#custom-elements) for some DevExtreme widget.

Comment: Is Aurelia custom element equivalent to directives or HTML web components?

Comment: According this [article](http://patrickwalters.net/best-parts-of-aurelia-1-composing-custom-elements-templates/): `Custom elements are web components that need to be imported or composed to use.`

Comment: My understanding is custom element follow the html web components standard, I can't find any references but I'm sure it has been mentioned in the various presentations.

Comment: Wish DevExpress or MVC 6 or Telerik Kendo had adapters for Aurelia. They are all supporting Angular.

Comment: @wonderfulworld: Aurelia bindings for Kendo are now available: http://blog.durandal.io/2016/01/28/aurelia-and-kendo-ui/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out the work of Stefan Heim.  He's created some prototype examples of DevExtreme/Aurelia integration.  There's a GitHub repository and demo available:

https://github.com/stenet/aurelia-devextreme

http://stefan.96.lt

Answer (score 1):

The most basic scenario follows these steps:

> 1) Create a new Aurelia app with aurelia-cli: [au new](https://github.com/aurelia/cli)
>
> 2) Install jquery: `npm install jquery --save`
>
> 3) Install devextreme: `npm install devextreme --save`

Here is the tricky part...in **aurelia_project** open aurelia.json and add this to vendor-bundle.js dependencies (can also use dx.all):

```
      {
        "name": "devextreme",
        "path": "../node_modules/devextreme/dist",
        "main": "js/dx.web"
      }
```

Add the devextreme css to index.html:

```
  <head>
    ...
    <!-- DevExtreme themes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.2.4/css/dx.common.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.2.4/css/dx.light.css" />
    ...
  </head>
```

And then a simple example in app.js and app.html will look like this:

app.html

```
    <template> 
        <div id="grid"></div>
    </template>
```

app.js

```
   export class App {

     attached() {

        $('#grid').dxDataGrid({
           dataSource: [{id: 1, name: 'Test'}]
        });

      }
    }
```