# Aurelia and devextreme integeration

Tags: aurelia, devextreme, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to integrate some libraries into an aurelia application. but sometimes importing modules are not working correctly!
for example, I want to use a devextreme UI widget in my app, but I have a problem:

```
import 'devextreme/ui/dialog';
...
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'dialog'
```

how can I integrate devextreme or any other third party modules with Aurelia?
I'm using dotnet aurelia template with its default module loader and using Typescript for scripting.

Comment: There is the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237680/devextreme-and-aurelia-integration)

Comment: try to create the Custom Elements for DevExtreme widget.